# In SwiftUI why does updating a View due to an ObserverObject change makes the Navigation pop there automatically?

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationlink, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a view in the navigation stack that depends on an ObservedObject that is changed later in time. When this change happens the navigation controller automatically pops there. Why is this happening and how to avoid it?

This is part of the code of the view

```
struct ProductDetailView: View {

    @ObservedObject var photosLibraryHelper = PhotosLibraryHelper.shared

    var body: some View {
...
        Button(action: {
                // What to perform
                print("tap")
            }) {
                if photosLibraryHelper.authorized{
                    NavigationLink(destination: ProductsView()){
                        CTAButton(title:"JUMP")
                    }
                }else{
                    NavigationLink(destination: PhotosPermissionView()){
                        CTAButton(title:"CREATE")
                    }
                }
            }
...
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I had to work around it. 
It’s not a nice solution btw.

Comment: In my case the problem was that I had a `ForEach` to create `NavigationLink`s and was not using an Identifiable element in the array.